# Python slackclient oauth.access call returning 'invalid_code' error

Tags: python, flask, slack, slack-api

I am using ngrok + flask + python slackclient to respond to Slack API's OAuth Flow and I am receiving an `invalid_code` error.

I am following steps described in [slackclient docs](https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/auth.html) and my code is pretty simple so far:

```
import os
import slack
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

SLACK_CLIENT_ID = os.environ['SLACK_CLIENT_ID']
SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ['SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET']

@app.route('/install', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def install():
    # Retrieve the auth code from the request params
    auth_code = request.args['code']

    # An empty string is a valid token for this request
    client = slack.WebClient(token='')

    # Request the auth tokens from Slack
    response = client.oauth_access(
        client_id=SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        code=auth_code
    )

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I initiate the App installation from the "Add" button in my Slack workspace's Manage Apps page. I can confirm that I am receiving a `code` as expected once the installation is initiated, and it is being correctly passed through to the `slack.BaseClient.api_call()` function that eventually sends the request to `https://slack.com/api/oauth.access`.

I expect the response from the `oauth_access` call to be a JSON object containing my access tokens, however, I get:

```
slack.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_code', 'warning': 'superfluous_charset', 'response_metadata': {'warnings': ['superfluous_charset']}}
```

I tried to send a POST with curl to Slack's endpoint with the required parameters and it worked as expected. I also tried with `requests.post()` and that also worked as expected. So I suspect that I am using slackclient incorrectly or have misunderstood something. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this occurring while using GET Route or POST?

Comment: @IshanJoshi Slack sends a GET to the `/install` route.

Comment: You should have a if condition to process GET and POST Requests differently

Comment: I'm not sure that would make a difference, though, since the error seems to be with the outbound `oauth_access` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the Python SDK. I think this pull request fixes this

https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/pull/527

In the meantime it may be easier to revert to version 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved in `v2.2.1` of `slackclient`

See [changelog](https://slack.dev/python-slackclient/changelog.html#v2-2-1-2019-10-08):

> [WebClient] Oauth previously failed to pass along credentials properly. This is fixed now. #527